# @ManyToMany relationship duplicates rows in table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to link mysql tables (role, user, user_role).

UserModel entity contains a field 'roles'.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Role entity contains a field 'users'

```
@Transient
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private UserModel users;
```

When i save a user, new rows are automatically created in the table 'roles'. How to cancel duplicate roles?

Answer (score 0):

You are cascading all operations from the `UserModel` over the `roles` attribute to entity `Role`. So whenever you persist a user, it persists its roles as well. Try removing the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or replace the cascading to something less "brute force".